# Extract columns from big data table to small data tables and save in a list

Tags: r, list, data.table, extract

I get a data table (time series for different products depending on dates) from an extern server, which can have the following maximal number of columns (date is always the first column, and all other columns can exists or not, or there are only two additional columns, or whatever):

```
set.seed(123)
dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                      'DEB Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'DEB Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'DEB Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'DEB Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'ATB Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'ATB Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'ATB Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'ATB Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'TTF Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'TTF Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'TTF Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'TTF Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'NCG Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'NCG Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'NCG Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'NCG Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'AUTVTP Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'AUTVTP Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'AUTVTP Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'AUTVTP Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'ATW Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'ATW Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'ATW Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'ATW Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'BRN Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'BRN Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'BRN Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'BRN Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      'FEUA MDEC1' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                      check.names = FALSE)
```

Now I would like to save / extract each occurring column with the date column in its own data table. Ideally, all extracted data tables are then added to a list. I know that I should somehow do this with a for loop, but I can't solve it.

After I have received individual data tables for each product, I would have to do the following for each of the data tables (an example data table is now used here for `AUTVTP Cal-2022`):

```
DT <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                 'AUTVTP Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), check.names = FALSE)


DT <- DT %>%
  mutate(month = format(date, '%b'), 
         date = format(date, '%d')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = 'AUTVTP Cal-2022') %>%
  relocate(`01`, .after = month)

## Calculate monthly and quarterly mean values: ##
DT <- setDT(DT)[, monthAvg := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = -1]
DT <- DT[, quartAvg := mean(monthAvg), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(DT))/3)]
DT <- DT[, yearAvg := mean(monthAvg), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(DT))/12)]

## Round all values of the data table to 2 digits: ##
DT <- DT %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)
```

HOW CAN I DO THIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape to long format, then split.

```
split(
  melt(dt.data, id.vars = "date"),
  by = "variable", keep.by = FALSE)
```

You can then use `lapply` to iterate over the list and do whatever your tidyverse code does.

However, generally you shouldn't split a data.table. It's inefficient and often not necessary.

**Edit:**

I suggest you forget the splitting. Wrap your code in a function like this:

```
foo <- function(DT, colname) {
  DT <- DT[, c("date", colname), with = FALSE]
  DT <- DT %>%
    mutate(month = format(date, '%b'), 
           date = format(date, '%d')) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = colname) %>%
    relocate(`01`, .after = month)
  
  ## Calculate monthly and quarterly mean values: ##
  DT <- setDT(DT)[, monthAvg := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = -1]
  DT <- DT[, quartAvg := mean(monthAvg), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(DT))/3)]
  DT <- DT[, yearAvg := mean(monthAvg), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(DT))/12)]
  
  ## Round all values of the data table to 2 digits: ##
  DT %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)
}
```

Then, when you need the table for a specific column in your shiny app, you can simply call this function:

```
foo(dt.data, 'DEB Cal-2019')
```

If you insist on pre-computing the list:

```
lapply(names(dt.data)[names(dt.data) != "date"], 
       foo, DT = dt.data)
```

Comment: When do I use the last part of the code, where I calculate the the monthly, quarterly and yearly means for each data table of the list?

Comment: You do that before you split. You can use `lapply` within a data.table to iterate over the columns.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the ```apply``` convention? As I need to calculate the monthly, quarterly and yearly means for each small data table, how can I do this before splitting?

Comment: By melting and using data.table's `by`.

Comment: I will try this, but I think I have to ask a new question because I don't really get it now.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add that to my answer? Then I can also accept your answer.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, the actual goal here is to calculate monthly and quarterly means for each column?

Comment: What I need is, to split the ```dt.data``` into small data tables (depending on how many columns the big data table has) -  ok that can be done by your ```split(melt(...))``` argument. After this step, I need to convert each of this small data tables to a wide/long format and calculate monthly, quarterly and yearly means and add it to the data table. My code for ```"AUTVTP Cal-2022"``` should simply be carried out for each individual small data table, and then save all data table in a ```list```. The problem is, that the number of columns varies.

Comment: So the mean calculation and the wide/lond format should remain the same as above in the code, but it should be valid for all existing data tables and not just for a single one (as here for ```"AUTVTP Cal-2022"```).

Comment: Your example code is of no use to me because it is written in tidyverse. I'm an old school R user who doesn't use that. Your explanation is very unclear. You should not start with splitting the data.table. If you must, you can end with that. I have still not understood what your actual goal is. And please don't explain with the steps you *think*  you need.

Comment: OK, I have to split up a large data table that contains a maximum of as many columns as already explained above and create a separate data table from each column with the date column. I want each of these individual data tables (with 2 columns) to be in a wide format (if you tried my code above, you would see what my data table should look like in the end). Since each of the data tables is in a wide format, three columns should be added at the end for each of these data tables with the monthly, quarterly and yearly mean values.

Comment: In the end, the entire data tables should be saved in a list, as I will use this list later in RShiny and not call up or display each of the data tables immediately.

My problem is not calculating the averages (monthly, quarterly, yearly) of a data table, nor changing a table to a wide format.
My problem is that I have different numbers of these single little data tables and I don't know how to automate that?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I want! The only thing I'm not sure about is how I can then access the individual elements of the list, because the list is indexed with ```[[1]]```, ```[[2]]```, ... etc. Would it also be possible that I can access via the column name?

Comment: See `help("setNames")`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of dataframes using `split.default` and `cbind` the first column to each list.

```
lapply(split.default(dt.data[, -1], names(dt.data[, -1])), cbind, dt.data[, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But then I still have to apply the second part of the code from above to each individual data table in the list (monthly, quarterly, yearly mean of each data table and all data tables transforming in a wide format).

Comment: From your question title and description that is what I get that you want to divide the data.table into two column list of data tables which my answer gives. If you write a function which you want to apply to each individual list, you can apply the function using `lapply` i.e `lapply(result_from_above, fun)`.